# Linear multiple regression with OLS in Python does not work

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am following a course in econometrics but I'm stuck unfortunately.

I hope you can help me.

The following model is given:  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfYCN.png

The OLS estimator of beta is given by:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7bHD.png

But when I run the following python script with very large sample size the estimators are terrible and do not converge to the true values. Could anyone explain this to me please?

'''

```
n = 100000
beta1 = 5.
beta2 = -.02
beta3 = .2


constant_term = np.ones(n)
X1 = np.linspace(10,30,n)
X2 = np.linspace(0,10,n)

X = np.column_stack((constant_term, X1, X2))

Y = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    u = np.random.normal(0.,1.)
    Y[i] = beta1 + beta2 * X[i,1] + beta3 * X[i,2] + u

Xt = np.transpose(X)

beta_ols = np.linalg.inv(Xt @ X) @ Xt @ Y

print(beta_ols)
```

'''
It returns for example [ 4.66326351 -0.32281745  0.87127398] but the true values are [5., -.02, .2]

I am aware that there also are function that can do this for me, but I want to do it manually to understand the material better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You variables `X` and `X2` are collinear, ie not linearly independent. Hence you matrix `Xt @ X` is not of full rank. Eigevalues:

```
np.linalg.eig(Xt @ X)[0]
```

prints

```
[4.65788929e+07, 3.72227442e-11, 1.87857084e+05]
```

note the second one is basically 0. Not exactly zero due to rounding etc. But when you invert this matrix you essentially divide by this very small number and massively lose precision. There are many ways to address it, for example look up [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization). In Python you can use `Ridge` regression from sklearn-kit

Of course if you do not want to get into finer details you can just modify your code to make sure your two variables are linearly independent, eg you can replace `X2` initialization with

```
X2 = np.linspace(0,10,n)**2
```